# Marking up a bottle of wine with Schema.org and Good Relations Product

Tags: microdata, schema.org

I have tried to mark up the kind of information you'd offer when you're selling a premium wine, here's what it looks like: [http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=dekoninck.co.uk%2Fwine.html](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=dekoninck.co.uk/wine.html).

The Rich Snippets Tools is showing "*Warning: Incomplete microdata with schema.org.*, and I can't work out what's missing.

Also, I'd love recommendations on

- the best way to mark up grape variety; currently done via `additionalType`
- the best way to mark up region; currently done via `additionalType`
- the best way to mark up producer; currently done via `manufacturer` which feels clunky
- the best way to specify vintage; currently done via `releaseDate` which feels clunky
- the best way to specify offering storage for wine; currently done via `businessFunction http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Maintain`
- how I can specify VAT/tax in pricing, for storage, wine price and delivery price.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it/126000#126000

Comment: Please post specific questions - _one_ specific question per question - with specific data incorporated into your post (ie, the part of the code that doesn't work).

Comment: Will do next time, thanks for the pointer. I'm new here and can now see one question per question makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked out what the warning means. It appears that the rich snippets testing tool no longer accepts Offer to be nested within Product.

Before I had

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
... details
    <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        ... details
    </div>
</div>
```

The fix (at least to make the warning disappear) is to move Product outside of Product:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
... details
</div>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    ... details
</div>
```

Does this look right?

Comment: Also, I missed the `itemprop="valueAddedTaxIncluded"` when I posted the question; that's the obvious way to add the tax/VAT information.